# Is there any way to fit an exponential model with a discrete predictor in R?

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, discrete-data, growth-model

I'm trying to estimate the growth rates of a number of ant colonies. I have measured colony mass at three different time points. I was thinking about measuring growth rate by fitting an exponential growth model to each colony's masses across time.

It was drawn to my attention that I may not be able to perform non-linear least squares (nls) as I had hoped, because the predictor is a discrete variable (i.e., it's t1, t2, or t3).

I was wondering:

1. whether this is indeed problematic &
2. whether anyone had any recommendations for how else to estimate growth rates in this case?

Comment: Do the $t$'s represent times? If so, do you know how far apart they are (such as, $t_1=0$, $t_2=24\text{ hours}$, etc)?

Comment: An exponential growth model typically has three parameters; *e.g.*, it can be expressed as $x = A + \exp(k t + b)$.  Provided the data are increasing, this guarantees a perfect fit in all cases: there is no need to use `nls`; you can solve for $A, k,$ and $b$ in terms of the the three data points.  If you dispense with $A$, that leaves only one degree of freedom.  `nls` will be useful, but it will exhibit very large standard errors for the estimates of $k$ and $b$.

Comment: @whuber: Is there not a typo in your comment? (Maybe you can edit it as a mod.) That is, I don't think the data being increasing are necessary or sufficient for a perfect fit. :)

Comment: @gung they do represent times. However, t3-t2 != t2-t1.

Comment: @whuber I hadn't thought about it that way. Any suggestions about how to extract that computationally? I tried to do it analytically, and stopped when I got to b=(t2/(t2-t1))*ln(y1-A)-(t1/(t2-t1))ln(y2-A)
lol.

Comment: @cardinal You are correct: "monotonic" should be read instead of "increasing."  In the present context, because "growth" implies increase, a monotonically decreasing sequence of values might be flagged for a separate or special analysis.

Comment: @whuber: I think the condition should be that the *slopes* between adjacent points are increasing, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Cardinal That's right, because I tucked the scale factor into the exponential as $\exp(b)$, which must be positive, rather than as a separate multiplier (which could be negative) of $\exp(kt)$.

Comment: So...any suggestions?